# how to solve system.runtime.interopservices.comexception error

Tags: asp.net, excel, datatable, webforms, office-interop

I export a datatable to an Excel file by using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel dll. When I run my project in localhost, Excel file is created. However, when I publish the project and run web site, I get this exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

I get it on this line:

```
Application excel = new Application();
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Don't use Interop! Why? because of all the issues, like the one you have. Use a specialized library, like EPPlus.

Comment: Please read https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office in order to understand why using the interop in a server environment is not a good idea. Note also that Office must be installed on the server where the code is running - that's not mentioned explicitly in the article...